# Oracle odp.net C# resultset update

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I want to update records in an active result set in ODP.NET (managed driver) C# env. (The function is query records, do not fetch all into the memory, process each records - call a webservice - and update a status record). In MS SQL it is require 2 connection, but Oracle can do it in Java:

```
public void modifyPrices(float percentage) throws SQLException {

Statement stmt = null;
try {
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
               ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    ResultSet uprs = stmt.executeQuery(
        "SELECT * FROM " + dbName + ".COFFEES");

    while (uprs.next()) {
        float f = uprs.getFloat("PRICE");
        uprs.updateFloat( "PRICE", f * percentage);
        uprs.updateRow();
    }

} catch (SQLException e ) {
    JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
} finally {
    if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
}}
```

.

Comment: What is your question? Event in Java it doesn't make scense to create a statement two times `stmt = con.createStatement();` - this call is useless

Comment: My question is how can I updete an open result set in C#?

Comment: What have you  tried? Do you have some code?

Comment: I never tryed it, I try to collect information first. I've some idea for this if CONCUR_UPDATABLE doesn't work but I want to make this perfectly.

Comment: It is a good approach. You could check [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx) classes because you will probably end up using these classes. You could also check the [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx) example which shows how you could update the table.

Comment: Ok, but DataSet fetch all records into the memory,

Comment: how many rows do you have?

Comment: It is indefinite, This job will load thousands to millions customer/potential customer record and put these to a direct mail campaign system via RESTfull webservice protocol one by one.

Comment: you could use the [OracleDataReader](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/win.111/b28375/OracleDataReaderClass.htm) to fetch the rows one by one, but it's a bit harder to update them. Probably, you will need some additional commands to perform the updates.